# Load a DLL From a Resource Directly From Memory in Delphi 7

Tags: delphi, dll, resources, delphi-7

I put a dll file into a resources file (*.res)

**ProjectTestLibrary.dll**

```
library ProjectTestLibrary;

uses SysUtils, Classes, Dialogs;

{$R *.res}

procedure DllMessage; export;
begin
  ShowMessage('Hello world from a Delphi DLL');
end;

exports DllMessage;

begin
end.
```

**MyTestDLL.rc**

```
TestDLL RCDATA ProjectTestLibrary.dll
```

**Produce MyTestDLL.res by this command line**

```
BRCC32 ProjectTestLibrary.rc
```

**In main form**

```
implementation
{$R *.dfm}
{$R MyTestDLL.RES}

procedure DllMessage;  stdcall; external 'ProjectTestLibrary.dll';

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
    DllMessage;
end;
```

Then error comes out
**This application has failed to start because ProjectTestLibrary.dll was not found.**

I understand that the problem because the dll file doesn't exist yet.
So I delete the 'DLLMessage;' code in onButton1Click.
Then onFormCreate, I added :

```
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var ms : TMemoryStream;
    rs : TResourceStream;
begin
  if 0 <> FindResource(hInstance, 'TestDLL', RT_RCDATA) then
  begin
    rs := TResourceStream.Create(hInstance, 'TestDLL', RT_RCDATA);
    ms := TMemoryStream.Create;
    ShowMessage('Found');
  end else
  begin
    ShowMessage('Not Found');
  end;
end;
```

I run it again then pop-up message said 'Found'

My question then :
1. How to save it in memory (not in PC hard drive), and finally
2. use its procedures/functions (procedure DLLMessage)

Comment: This is not supported by the OS. To do so requires something like BTMemoryModule which may fail on future windows releases. It relying on implementation detail. Anti malware software will likely regard this activity as dubious. Always better to ship the DLL alongside the exe.

Answer (score 0):

There is no official way to do it, although there exist techniques which emulate the Windows PE loader, and let you load DLL directly from a memory buffer, without having to store it on disk.

Here is a Delphi implementation, for example, of a DLL memory loader: https://github.com/DSPlayer/memorymodule